# Azure DevOps > Library | Get the variable value from a variable group into the build.gradle of Android Project

Tags: android, groovy, azure-devops, build.gradle

I need to generate a versionCode and VersionName in Azure DevOps, and I've a variable created in the Azure DevOps Library

- Major: 1
- Minor: 4
- Patch: 4

Now, in the app module's "**build.gradle**" I want to read these variables.

I tried the below, but it's not working:

```
def major = findProperty('major') != null ? "${findProperty('major')}" : "1"
def minor = findProperty('minor') != null ? "${findProperty('minor')}" : "1"
def patch = findProperty('patch') != null ? "${findProperty('patch')}" : "1"
def buildNumber = findProperty('buildNumber') != null ? "${findProperty('buildNumber')}" : "0"

android {
  ...
  defaultConfig {
    ...
    versionName "${major}.${minor}.${patch}"
    versionCode "${buildNumber}"
}
```

Unfortunately, I'm not able to get the variable values here. The versionName will only generate **1.1.1**

Any idea why this isn't working? I need to use the Groovy to obtain this.

Thanks